# Variance deduction

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

the definition of variance is  $V(X) = E((X-E(X))^2 )$

For a discrete random variable: if  we have put $Y = g(X)$ , where $g$ is a real function

$E(Y) = E(g(X)) = \sum\limits_{k} g(k)p_X(k)$  , where $p_X(k) = P(X = k) $

how can i use this formula to show that:

$V(X) = \sum\limits_{k} (k-E(X))^2 p_X(k)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: set $g(k)=(k-\mathbf{E}X)^2$

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}(X)
&=\mathrm{E}\left((X-\color{#C00000}{\mathrm{E}(X)})^2\right)\\
&=\sum_k\overbrace{\left(k-\color{#C00000}{\sum_jjp_X(j)}\right)^2}^{g(k)}p_X(k)\\
&=\sum_k\left(k^2-2k\sum_jjp_X(j)+\left(\sum_jjp_X(j)\right)^2\right)p_X(k)\\
&=\sum_kk^2p_X(k)-2\left(\sum_kkp_X(k)\right)\left(\sum_jjp_X(j)\right)+\left(\sum_jjp_X(j)\right)^2\\
&=\sum_kk^2p_X(k)-\left(\sum_kkp_X(k)\right)^2
\end{align}
$$
The last formula is the expected value of $X^2$ minus $(\text{the expected value of }X)^2$, which is the variance.